# Дубликат сайт отличается от оригинала

Tags: wordpress

Есть два сайта 1. bosbiz.ru и 2.goodgu.ru Сделала через плагин Дубликатор копию сайта 1. и установила его создав отдельную базу данных, создав сайт 2. Но меню поплыло, все настройки такие же. Когда находишься в режиме редактирования Elementor, то все выглядит нормально, как на изначальном сайте, переходишь на сайт и там не так. Не работает даже заголовок как на первом сайте и многое другое.

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2):

В общем у кого такие же проблемы, зайдите в админ панель Elementor-Инструменты-Сменить URL В одной строке введите название оригинала сайт, во втором окошке дубликата. И нажмите сменить!

Comment: дупликатор это должен был сделать. Ты наверное как-то неправильно переносила.

Answer (score 0):

К написанному добавил бы:

1. Обновите Permalinks;
2. Почистите кэш, соответственно проверьте сайт в браузере в Режиме инкогнито
3. Наконец удостоверьтесь, что дупликатор действительно все добавил в архив, не стояло ли в его установках дополнительных фильтов?